# Adding an additional character to the range function

Tags: php

```
range($low, $high, $step)
```

Create an array containing a range of elements

I would like to put my range as 1 - 12 but than add another option for 99. Can i do this by creating a variable and than passing the variable into the array?

```
<?php $infin = range(1,12,99); ?>
```

I'm not really sure how to accomplish this but it seems easy and i'm kind of drawing blanks right now.

Comment: cant you just do `range()` and `array_push` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$infin = range(1, 12);
$infin[] = 99;
```

The second line allows you to add a new element to the end of an array.

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
    [4] => 5
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 7
    [7] => 8
    [8] => 9
    [9] => 10
    [10] => 11
    [11] => 12
    [12] => 99
)
```

Comment: and for using the same variable as the OP. :)

Comment: I will mark as the correct answer when the time allows me too. Still have over 8 minutes. Cheers guys!

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = range(1, 12);
$array[] = 99;
```

Comment: That's the normal syntax for adding a new element to an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$infin=array_merge(range(1,12),array(99));
```

Comment: You might want to change `$range` to `range`